# Does showing that $a_{kn}$ converges for all integral k>1 imply $a_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a_{kn} \rightarrow L_k$ for all integral $k>1$, does that mean $a_n\rightarrow L$?

Note: I can already prove $L_{k_1} = L_{k_2}$ for all $k_1,k_2$ i.e. all k yields the same limit.

Proof: if $a_{k_1n} \rightarrow L_{k_1}$ and $a_{k_2n} \rightarrow L_{k_2}$, the subsequence $a_{k_1k_2n}$ is a subsequence of both $a_{k_1n}$ and $a_{k_2n}$ so $a_{k_1k_2n} \rightarrow L_{k_1},L_{k_2}$ which by uniqueness of limits shows $L_{k_1}=L_{k_2}$ for all $k_1,k_2$.

From this, is it possible to prove my initial question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the sequence $a_n$ defined by $a_n$ is $1$ if $n$ is prime, else $a_n$ is zero.

Comment: oooh so all $L_k =0$ but $a_n$ itself diverges because there is always another prime?

Comment: Right.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

quasi's idea stretched a bit :

Let $p$ be prime.

Consider: $a_n =1/p,$ for $n=p$, else $0.$

The harmonic series with primes (only) diverges.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicSeriesofPrimes.html

Comment: Doesn't this approach 0?

Comment: Aakash.Have s look at the above link.As I understand even summing over the primes only , the sum diverges, slowly, but it does .I think , quite remarkable.

Comment: just realized you meant the series of a! thank you!

Comment: Nice isn't it. Fewer primes than positive integers and the harmonic series diverges!